# Can't add class to element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have problem that is unexplainable to me. I have a simple `<svg>` element with "normal" class--> `"small_circle_svg_menu"`. And I want to add a class `"animated"` to that element. I mean that's the simplest thing and I can't do it right but can do some much more complicated things.

Here's what I do to add a class to element. I tried to add class in two ways. First way is the simple function which checks if element has that class and if the element don't have it add's it to element.
The second way is the simplest thing ever(you'll see).

**This is the first way:**
This function adds class normally to any other element. I also logged the `document.getElementsByClassName('small_circle_svg_menu')[0]` to console to see if I'm maybe logging wrong element. (But that was not the case, I was logging right element).

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
  return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}
function addClass(ele,cls) {
  if (!this.hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

addClass(document.getElementsByClassName('small_circle_svg_menu')[0],"animated")
```

**The second way:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('small_circle_svg_menu')[0].className += "animated"
```

Element in HTML is positioned in `<header>` so I'll show you whole `<header>`.

```
    <header >
      <div class=" menu_circle circles-div ">
        <div class="icn__wrap menu " id="menu">
          <i class="icn__hamburger state_1"  id="icn__hamburger-1" ></i>
          <i class="icn__hamburger state_1"  id="icn__hamburger-2" ></i>
          <i class="icn__hamburger state_1"  id="icn__hamburger-3" ></i>
          <svg class="small_circle_svg_menu  "  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="58px" height="58px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" preserveAspectRatio="none"  >
                      <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="6.215" transform="rotate(90 8 8)" stroke="white" class="small-circle" id="menu_circle"></circle>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    <img id="logo" src="images/nolo.png" alt="nole.logo"  onclick="fullpage.moveTo(1)"/>
    <div class="page-title background_LG"id="prvinatpis"                >Novak Djokovic</div>
    <div class="page-title background_LG"id="drugastrananatpis"   >News                </div>
    <div class="page-title background_LG"id="trecastrananatpis"    >Tour                  </div>
    <div class="page-title background_LG"id="cetvrtastrananatpis" >Story                 </div>
    <div class="page-title background_LG"id="petastrananatpis"     >Gallery               </div>
</header>
```

Also I want to mention that I didn't get any error in console so far.First and only time I get error is when using first way. Then I get this error.

```
TypeError: ele.className.match is not a function.
(In 'ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'))', 'ele.className.match' is undefined)
```

Comment: `classList.add('class-name')`

Comment: solved,but can somebody explain me why my methods didn't worked

Comment: `.className += "animated"` needs a space `.className += " animated"` ;) --- Not sure why you're functions didn't work though.

Comment: `this` is not defined in `addClass` or even if, `hasClass` is no member of any class.

Comment: @CodeSpirit that are not mine functions,I found them on Github.But so far they worked without any problems.Can you please specify what I should do to make them work for that element,also noticed that "addClass" doesn't work for also some other elements,but for most of them works

Comment: Ok,I tried to select every element ,and works for every element except <svg> elements,I DON'T HAVE ANY IDEA WHY ,somebody knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your element use the method `classList.add()`.

```
var element = document.getElementById("my-class");
element.classList.add("class-name");
```

Search your prefer element with `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `classList` is supported by svg?